# Replace String Text with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement emoticons so for example `:happy:` should display an emoticon. However, the text is sanitized and does not generate the actual html.

How can I replace certain strings such as `:happy:` with html image?

#### Current attempt (replace `:happy:` with html):

```
  var data = snapshot.val();
  var username = data.name || "anonymous";
  var message = data.text;

  // REPLACE STRING WITH IMAGE
  message = message.replace(":happy:", "<img src='https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/static/emoticons/1.0.jpg'>");

  //CREATE ELEMENTS MESSAGE & SANITIZE TEXT
  var messageElement = $("<li>");
  nameElement.text(username);
  messageElement.text(": "+message).prepend(nameElement);

  //DISPLAY MESSAGE
  messageList.append(messageElement)
```

#### Update:

I think something like `text.splitText()` should be used here. But I'm trying to find the best way to `find` the text, then `split` it.

Comment: try messageElement.html(": "+message).prepend(nameElement);

Comment: try messageElement.html()

Comment: @annshuk Yes, but I don't want the entire message to be html safe. It is still user input.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.html()` to have an element effect. `.text()` will just put the content without having any `HTML` effect

```
messageElement.html(": "+message).prepend(nameElement);
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the entire message to be html safe. It is still user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single detached DOM element to sanitize the inputs, then convert strings to images.

Done by setting `Node.textContent`[[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)] and getting `Element.innerHTML`[[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)] on the detached node.
Then using `String.prototype.replace()`[[mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)] method on the resulting string.

This is **library free**.

```js
var username = "anonymous",
    message = "Some text with an happy <b>emoticon</b> :happy: and a sad <i>emoticon</i> :sad:.",
    messageList = document.getElementById("messageList"),
    sanitizer = document.createElement("p");

  //CREATE ELEMENTS MESSAGE
  var messageElement = document.createElement("li");

  //SANITIZE TEXT
  sanitizer.textContent = message;
  message = sanitizer.innerHTML;

  //REPLACE STRING WITH IMAGE
  message = message.replace(":happy:", "<img src='https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/horde.tv/static/emoticons/1.0.jpg'>");
  message = message.replace(":sad:", "<img src='https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/emoticons/v1/86/1.0'>");
  messageElement.innerHTML = username + ": " + message;

  //DISPLAY MESSAGE
  messageList.appendChild(messageElement);
```

```html
<ul id="messageList"></ul>
```